# Java code for fetching LinkedIn profile

Tags: java, linkedin-api, pom.xml

I need to write a **java class to access a particular LinkedIn profile** with photo and retrieve/display the profile given the first and last name or id.
 Can someone help point in the right direction? Are LinkedIn java APIs available to be used - if yes, what should my Maven project pom.xml contain?

Answer (score 0):

API's are not language specific you can call API from any language.

This is the  link of linkedin API : https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/rest-api#!

Now what you have to do is call this API (Do authentication if required in API) in background thread and get the data and when thread finish it's work than set the image and name in required place.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes It's Posible. Just have a [look](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs)
[Refer](http://javacompleteexamples.blogspot.com/2010/03/linkedin-api-integration-in-java.html) this Blog as an example of LinkedIn API in Java.

The versions can be different of this POM example( or get it from [here](https://github.com/linkedin/api-get-started/blob/master/java/pom.xml))

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.linkedin.sample</groupId>
  <artifactId>api-get-started</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.scribe</groupId>
          <artifactId>scribe</artifactId>
          <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
          <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
          <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
          <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Hope this helps